# php/mysql: select query doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql

sorry for not having a good title. because i dont really know the keyword to use,. 
i have a table named document
and i have a column name status and number

i have data something like this
3 sets of data
1.

```
number -1 status-signed
number -1 status-signed
number -1 status-declined
```

i have a html table in my php website

what i want is not show a data if one of its status is declined
so basically number 1 will not appear on the html table

so how can i query that. i have something like this

```
select number, status from table document where status !="declined" and status = "signed" group by number
```

but that query don't work., it keeps showing the number with declined status in it.

sorry for my bad english

as stated by the answers below i tried this sql

```
select number
from  document 
group by number
having sum(`status` <> 'declined') > 0 and
   sum(`status` = 'signed') > 0;
```

but the query above doesnt work because it keep showing the number 1. that must not be included. how can i fix this? thank you
this is the data ony my table

[image]

Comment: post the data it returns and define `doesnt work`

Comment: i already stated it above sir. before i updated the question. thank you

Comment: why not use a simple queru `select status, number from document where status <> "declined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with a `having` clause, rather than a `where` clause.  That is, do the comparisons *after* aggregation:

```
select number
from table document 
group by number
having sum(status <> 'declined') > 0 and
       sum(status = 'signed') > 0;
```

If you want the statuses, you can add `group_concat(status)` to the `select`.

EDIT:

If you want to filter out numbers with a decline, then change the `having` clause:

```
select number
from table document 
group by number
having sum(status = 'declined') = 0 ;
```

Comment: the question above is update sir. i applied the you're suggestion.  but still doesn't work sir. can you please help me. thank you

Comment: hello sir. can you help me again. im having problems with the where statement (select number, status, idnum
from table document where idnum = "0001"
group by number
having sum(status = 'declined') = 0 ; ) the idnum 0001 are in the number 1 and 2. but number 1 have a declined status. so the output must be number 2 only. but it keeps showing the number 1. maybe because of the where statement? how can i solve it thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select number
from table document 
group by number
having sum(`status` <> 'declined') > 0 and
   sum(`status` = 'signed') > 0;
```

status is a keyword

Comment: i updated the question above sir. but the query doesn't work properly. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Given

> not show a data if one of its status is declined

The correct query is

```
select number
from  document 
group by number
having sum(`status` = 'declined') = 0 and
   sum(`status` = 'signed') > 0
```

sum(`status` <> 'declined') > 0

means getting all numbers where at least one row is not equal do declined